# Swift get HTML from URL

Tags: html, ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to get and print the HTML from a URL. Here's how I do it (with Swift 2):

```
let testUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
var html = NSString()
do {
    html = try NSString(contentsOfURL: testUrl!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch{print(error)}
print(html)
```

And the following error is printed in console:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo={NSURL=https://www.google.com, NSStringEncoding=4}

Any idea?

Comment: oh nvm, changing `encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding` to `encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding` solve it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453711/contentsoffile-returning-nil-possible-cause-swift This guy had a similar error.

Comment: would you please mention what version of xcode you are using

Comment: @AlexLing: NSASCIIStringEncoding cannot represent any non-ASCII characters. So even if it does not crash, NSASCIIStringEncoding is almost always a bad choice.

Comment: @jamil65able I am using Xcode 7.0 GM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that www.google.com sends the response using the
[ISO 8859-1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), the corresponding `NSString` encoding is `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`:

```
html = try NSString(contentsOfURL: testUrl!, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
```

You can also detect the HTTP response encoding automatically,
see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/1187415.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but when I tried another url like https://www.google.com/search?q=%20site:%20stackoverflow.com I got an error saying that  The file “search” couldn’t be opened. I've tried different encodings but none of them work.

Comment: @AlexLing: `let testUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=%20site:%20stackoverflow.com")` with the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding does work for me. The error message *"The file “search” couldn’t be opened"* seems to be unrelated to the encoding to me.

Comment: Saved my life!!!! I was trying to download a .svg image as String and persisting it for showing in a WKWebView, even if the user is offline. This finally solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 Solution:

```
do {

html = try NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.isoLatin1.rawValue)

} catch let error {

  print(error)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Solution:

```
try! String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://www.google.com"), encoding: .utf16)
```